# how to pass grid data in a gridview template textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a  grid view name gvwsponsoor and it has 8 cells every cells has template textbox. if i  am double click this textbox then open a model popup. i selected this popup data the data is show the textbox. but second rows are not show data, always data show first rows, how to pass all rows show data, please tell me solution any person .

i try to solved this code but not work in this code.

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        //foreach (GridViewRow grid in gvwSponsor.Rows) 
        //{
        TextBox CostId = (TextBox)gvwSponsor.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("txtCostCenter");
        TextBox CostName = (TextBox)gvwSponsor.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDescription");
        CostId = (TextBox)gvwSponsor.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("txtCostCenter");
        CostName = (TextBox)gvwSponsor.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDescription");
            CostId.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            CostName.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;


        DataTable dtaa = new DataTable();
        dtaa = bll.GetNumber(CostId.Text);
        if (dtaa.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = dtaa;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
         TextBox TxtOp = (TextBox)gvwSponsor.Rows[0].FindControl("txtOP");
         TxtOp.Focus();
                   //}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should process SelectedIndexChanged function of your gridview by using gvwSponsor.SelectedRow, not gvwSponsor.Rows[0]